# How to abbreviate "Local" for a time variable, like UTC

Tags: naming

In a database I work on, most of the datetimes I store are converted to and from UTC so all of my datetime columns end in UTC such as `CanceledUTC`.

I have a situation where I need to store a "local" time and want to signify that it is a local time in the column name.

**Is there a convention for signifying *local* datetime variable names?**

I know that storing "local" datetimes is a bad practice so I'm also considering storing it as a string, but that's not the question here.

Comment: You mean the column _names_, right?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Haha, yeah.  I try and switch up my words when asking questions so other people searching can find it because this question doesn't just apply to column names.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski: What else does it apply to? I would advise sticking with proper terminology so that we know what you're talking about, rather than "switching up" your words...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In my current context (the database), `Canceled` is a *column* name, but when I start programming, it will be a *variable* name.  That's why I used both words.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski: Then your chosen terminology "column" was incorrect for both your current use case, and your future use case! lol

Answer (score 5):

**Nothing.**

The name of the column should be *CancelledTime* or *CancelledAt*, and the column should have type `TIMESTAMP`. It will be stored timezone-agnostically, but automatically have the timezone of the session taken into consideration when values are inserted and retrieved.

If that is not possible for some reason, then fine make it a `DATETIME` … but give it a `COMMENT` line that indicates the field values are local time representations. This really seems like a bad idea, though: local time *when*? Insert before daylight savings, retrieve after daylight savings → you're hosed.

Certainly, though, information about the data representation doesn't belong in the field name. What the data *is* belongs in the field name. And your data is (presumably) "the time at which a thing was cancelled".